# ServiceStack DTOs on MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack

We're creating a webservice with ServiceStack (current v3-fixes branch) and another company is programming an Android and iOS App against it.

My DTOs are (of course) in separate assemblies and compiled against .Net Framework 4. I can use these assemblies without problems in .Net projects and also in the Xamarin.Android project. The other company now told me, that they are not working in Xamarin.iOS.

They are using the latest (precompiled) ServiceStack.MonoTouch dlls with version 3.9.55. I read somewhere that I have to compile my DTOs against the MonoTouch version of the ServiceStack dlls.

Is this correct and is it possible to do this in a windows environment?

Thanks in advance
Steffen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is true you will need to compile your DTO's against the MonoTouch version of the ServiceStack dlls. The reason for this is because Xamarin.iOS does not support the full desktop version of the .NET assemblies. Rather it is a subset of them, much like the Silverlight platform. [See here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies/) for more information.

> Note: Xamarin.iOS is not ABI compatible with existing assemblies compiled for a different profile. You must recompile your source code to generate assemblies targeting the Xamarin.iOS profile (just as you need to recompile source code to target Silverlight and .NET 3.5 separately).

While Xamarin does have a Visual Studio plugin, Xamarin doesn't support Xamarin.iOS without a Mac OS X environment. There are services online where you can hire remote Mac OS X systems.

Comment: Hi Scott. This is exactly the information I needed, thank you very much.